# Summation of multiple calculations

Tags: python, loops, sum, iteration

[image]

I'm trying to make the calculation you can see in the screenshot more compact. Is there a way I can write the calculation in only one line?

My problem is that I don't know how to make the summation with all these different frequencies in just one line.

Comment: It wouldn't be "one line", but you could add an inner loop that loops over the frequencies, adding those terms to the initial term.  Or, you you sum a list comprehension and add it to the initial term.  I don't know if the person who downvoted saw this as too basic a question, or if it's because you posted a screenshot instead of your code. It'd be nice if downvoters commented. However, posting your code makes it more likely for people to post answers.

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but I guess that it is the picture. Code as picture is problematic, because a human cannot simply try out the code by copy and paste. @yessir22 I would recommend you to remove the picture and post a textual code snippet with \`\`\`code\`\`\`.

Comment: Is `data` a list of lists? Or a dictionary of lists?  And can you post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving you a direct answer of your question, I recommend you thinking about your data structures to make your life a bit easier. Having two lists which are dependent from each other often make things more complicated than necessary.

Imagine you first transfer your data structure into one data structure (`dict`), i.e. something like this:

```py
data = {
    "25 Hz": {"num": 1},
    "40 Hz": {"num": 2},
    ...
}
```

Then you can simply iterate over the values, sum them up and apply log10 at the end:

```py
result = 0
for item in data.values():
    result += 10 ** item["num"] * (1/10)
result = 10 * math.log10(result)
```

This can also be done as a one-liner as requested:

```py
10 * math.log10(sum(10 ** item["num"] * (1/10) for item in data.values()))
```

If you only need a subset from the data, you can filter the rest out, e.g.:

```py
subset = {"40 Hz", "100 Hz"}
10 * math.log10(sum(10 ** item["num"] * (1/10) for freq, item in data.items() if freq in subset))
```

If you're really interested in having a one-liner with the given data structure, then I hope that you have some inspiration from my answer. You will probably end with a double iteration, which is likely to be less performant. A one-liner is imho fine as long it is still understandable. Otherwise I would recommend keeping a simple for iteration or a delegation to a function call.